# How to manage storing and showing date in different formats?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access, .net-3.5

I am getting date in forms in dd/MM/yyyy format but in database it is not the format to store the date. Here I am facing difficulties.

Please guide me how I should manage it

Requirement is just that user should enter date in dd/mm/yyyy format and on viewing data it should be shown in same format. Problems occur when I get input and save it, on fetching data it shows wrong date/ format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should assume *particular format* while inputting the data. You can use methods such as [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee1y0t7.aspx) to convert your input string in particular format to date/time data type. Store the value in database as date/time data type (and not character/string data type). While retrieving and displaying value, use [DateTime.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) to convert into particular format.

Comment: +1 - Formatting and parsing is a presentation tier concern. OP should use Native Date storage for memory and database.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you save the date as a [smalldatetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) in the database. You can convert the string to a .net `DateTime` object by doing a `DateTime.Parse("dd/MM/yyyy")`. After fetching the date from the database you can display in the correct format by converting it into a string with `theDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`.

Comment: Uh, smalldatetime is a SQL Server data type, right? What does that have to do with an Access/Jet/ACE database?

Comment: @David the question is tagged sql-server, isn't it?

Comment: Then I'm quite confused as to why it's tagged Access at all -- if the database is SQL Server and the programming environment is C#, what's Access doing in the mix?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to format the output using `.ToString();`
[Check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)